# Look up 10 million transformation in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I was doing some test using a data flow task with look up. The source is an excel sheet with 10 million records and destination is 10 million records. In the look up task I am using partial cache mode. However I have noiced that its taking very long time. round about 10 mins!!

I have noticed that validation phase itself is taking 2/3 minutes..Is there any way to optimize the complete task?

Comment: You are loading data from an Excel worksheet. What is the source for your Lookup component? Did you write the query or select the table in the drop down? What version of SQL Server are you using? What was your reason for choosing Partial Cache? How do you have partial cache configured - allowable memory?

Comment: Source is Excel connection. No I didnt write a SQL query,Rather I selected the sheets. This is SQL server 2008. I choose partial cache is that my system is not of good configuration and there are 10 million rows that need to be updated. Full cache was taking a long time. Allowable memory is 25 MB.

Comment: I am doing this test on my laptop which is a 1.6 Ghz, 2 GB RAM. the SQL server I am using is 2008 32 bit. I also tried using full cache mode but it was hung/stuck just after it  cached 10 million rows. Pleae suggest some best pracrtices or methods to have an optimal performance in this scenario

Comment: @Dasso Just checking. In lookup transformation, Keep only lookup columns instead of all columns.

Comment: But the lookup component itself - you have an Excel Spreadhsheet there too?

Comment: @ram.bi I just have the look up columns in the lookup transformation, not all columns.

Comment: @billinkc, not its looking up to a SQL server table.

Comment: @Dasso How many columns in your lookup ? 
And give a try by using cache transformation. and use this cache transformation in Lookup.

Comment: I have 1 lookup column and 3 output columns. Today I am trying the cache transformation. Will post the findings